# How check if action exsist in Controller Plugin preDispatch

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-controller-plugin

I have two modules (default and mobile) the module mobile is a rewrite the default portal in jquery mobile but with much less controllers and actions!
I thought of write a controller plugin that check if controller and action exist in module mobile, if not I would like overwrite the module mobile to default.
I try this:

```
public function dispatchLoopStartup(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
{
    $dispatcher = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getDispatcher();
    if ($request->getModuleName() == 'mobile') {      
        if (!$dispatcher->isDispatchable($request)) {
            // Controller or action not exists
            $request->setModuleName('default');
        }
    }
    return $request;
}
```

but `$dispatcher->isDispatchable($request)` return always `true` though the action not exist! :S 
and i receive "Action `foo` does not exist and was not trapped in __call()"

How can I do?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever wondered how to check if a controller/action exist in zend FM from any side of app ? Here is the code

```
    $front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
    $dispatcher = $front->getDispatcher();

    $test = new Zend_Controller_Request_Http();
    $test->setParams(array(
        'action' => 'index',
        'controller' => 'content',

            )
    );

    if($dispatcher->isDispatchable($test)) {
        echo "yes-its a controller";
        //$this->_forward('about-us', 'content'); // Do whatever you want
    } else {
        echo "NO- its not a Controller";
    }
```

**EDIT**

Check like this way

```
$classMethods = get_class_methods($className);
 if(!in_array("__call", $classMethods) &&
 !in_array($this->getActionMethod($request), $classMethods))
 return false;
```

and also please see [detail link](http://osdir.com/ml/php.zend.framework.mvc/2008-02/msg00631.html)

Comment: not work! In my case the controller exist but the action no and the `$dispatcher->isDispatchable($test)` return always `true`!!!

Comment: Thanks for your reply but as defined $className?

Comment: have you checked link

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you make a static or dynamic routes either via config resource manager, bootstrap or via front controller plugin:

Example of defining static routes in Bootstrap.php:

```
public function _initRoutes()
{
    $front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
    $router = $front->getRouter(); // default Zend MVC routing will be preserved

    // create first route that will point from nonexistent action in mobile module to existing action in default module
    $route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Static(
        'mobile/some-controller/some-action', // specify url to controller and action that dont exist in "mobile" module
        array(
            'module' => 'default', // redirect to "default" module
            'controller' => 'some-controller',
            'action' => 'some-action', // this action exists in "some-controller" in "default" module
        )
    );
    $router->addRoute('mobile-redirect-1', $route); // first param is the name of route, not url, this allows you to override existing routes like default route

    // repeat process for another route
}
```

This would effectively route request for **/mobile/some-controller/some-action** to **/default/some-controller/some-action**

**some-controller** and **some-action** should be replaced with proper controller and action names.

I was using static routing which is ok if you route to exact urls, but since most applications use additional params in url for controller actions to use, it is better to use dynamic routes.
In above example simply change route creation class to `Zend_Controller_Router_Route` and route url to `"mobile/some-controller/some-action/*"` and every request will be routed dynamically like in example:

```
/mobile/some-contoller/some-action/param1/55/param2/66 
will point to 
/default/some-controller/some-action/param1/55/param2/66
```

For more info about routing in ZF1 check [this link](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.router.html)

Comment: this strategy is not good because I have to be able to understand what you're asking to be able to change the layout to be set! :S

Comment: just because you dont understand it does not mean it is a bad strategy ;) I'll edit my answer to make it more clear

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I do not like this strategy, because if in the future I add new shares in the project, I am forced to add a route, while I would like a method that was good for all seasons! :D

Comment: Check out the link about ZF1 routing, things like that can be solved via dynamic routing. Also, there are loads of routing questions on stackoverflow you can check.